# Updating object properties returned by LiveData

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have a question around the best practice for updating object properties of an object fetched from Room by LiveData.

Currently when my observer is triggered in my activity, I take the returned object and pass it back to the view-model to keep a reference and then update the properties through the setters defined in the view-model and then update the object in Room

My question is is this considered a best practice or is there a better way to achieve this?

I know about MutableLiveData but that would require me to fetch each of the individual object properties, update them and then resale each one, whereas I would prefer to just fetch the object, update that and resave?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as the Object retrieved from the LiveData itself (Let's call it Object A) is not use as a future reference object, sure that works.

So if you do the following, it's a good solutions:

1. Activity action
2. ViewModel calls load Object A
3. Object A is placed inside LiveData
4. LiveData is observed in Activity
5. Observed Object A is passed to function ViewModel
6. Function in ViewModel updates property in Object A
7. Updated Object A is set to Object B reference in ViewModel
8. When Object is needed, Object B is referenced in ViewModel